# Kotlin unit tests fails on github but pass locally

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

```
class HomeViewModelTest {

    private var parkingService: ParkingService = mockk()
    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel
    private lateinit var loadingState: MutableList<LoadingState>
    private val parkingLotUsersCount: MutableMap<String, MutableSet<String>> = mutableMapOf()

    @get:Rule
    val rule = MainDispatcherRule()

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        clearAllMocks()
    }


    @Test
    fun `Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLots is called and fails, should return FAILURE loading state`()= runTest {
        viewModel = HomeViewModel(parkingService)
        loadingState = mutableListOf()
        viewModel.loadingStateLiveData.observeForever {
            loadingState.add(it)
        }

        val location = Pair(0.0, 0.0)
        val showProgressLoader = true

        coEvery {
            parkingService.getParkingLots()
        } returns null

        viewModel.getParkingLots(location, showProgressLoader)

        coVerify {
            parkingService.getParkingLots()
        }
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(LoadingState.FAILURE, viewModel.loadingStateLiveData.value)
    }


    @Test
    fun `Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLots is called and succeeds, should return SUCCESS loading state`() = runTest {

        viewModel = HomeViewModel(parkingService)

        loadingState = mutableListOf()

        viewModel.loadingStateLiveData.observeForever {
            loadingState.add(it)
        }

        val location = Pair(0.0, 0.0)
        val showProgressLoader = true
        val response = ParkingLotsResponse(
            listOf(
                parking_lots("1234", 0.0, 0.0, "https://detectionlog.s3.amazonaws.com/original_images/2023-05-14T13:42:24.838578_uu8ca0j.jpg", 10, "$10", "Lot1", "1hr", "timestamp", 20)
            )
        )

        coEvery { parkingService.getParkingLots() } returns response

        viewModel.getParkingLots(location, showProgressLoader)

        advanceTimeBy(1000L)

        coVerify { parkingService.getParkingLots() }

        assertEquals(LoadingState.SUCCESS, viewModel.loadingStateLiveData.value)
    }


    @Test
    fun `Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLotInfo is called and succeeds, should return list of parking lots info`()= runTest  {
        viewModel = HomeViewModel(parkingService)
        loadingState = mutableListOf()
        viewModel.loadingStateLiveData.observeForever {
            loadingState.add(it)
        }
        val response = ParkingLotsResponse(
            listOf(
                parking_lots("1234",0.0, 0.0, "https://detectionlog.s3.amazonaws.com/original_images/2023-05-14T13:42:24.838578_uu8ca0j.jpg", 10, "$10", "Lot1", "1hr", "timestamp", 20)
            )
        )
        val parkingLotInfoResp = ParkingLotInfo("Lot1", 12)

        parkingLotUsersCount["Lot1"] = mutableSetOf("12")
        coEvery {
            parkingService.getParkingLotInfo("Lot1")
        } returns parkingLotInfoResp

        viewModel.getNumberOfUsersForParkingLots(response)

        advanceTimeBy(1000L)

        coVerify {
            parkingService.getParkingLotInfo(response.parking_lots[0].parking_lot_name)
        }

        assertEquals(
            parkingLotUsersCount["Lot1"].toString(),
            viewModel.parkingLotUsersCount["Lot1"].toString()
        )

    }

    @Test
    fun `Given current location when getNearestParkingLot is called, should verify correct parking lot is found`()= runTest  {
        viewModel = HomeViewModel(parkingService)
        loadingState = mutableListOf()
        viewModel.loadingStateLiveData.observeForever {
            loadingState.add(it)
        }
        val currentLocation = Pair(44.57317333333334, -123.282065)
        val mockApiResponse = ParkingLotsResponse(listOf(
            parking_lots("1234",44.568078130296776, -123.279363220437, "https://detectionlog.s3.amazonaws.com/original_images/2023-05-14T13:42:24.838578_uu8ca0j.jpg", 12, "2", "Johnson Hall", "2 Hr Parking [ 7.00 am to 5.00 pm]", "2023-04-29 18:51:40", 36),
            parking_lots("1234",44.56298278509426, -123.27235573138302, "https://detectionlog.s3.amazonaws.com/original_images/2023-05-30T20:14:51.395821_gotlchv.jpg", 3, "2", "Tebeau Hall", "2 Hr Parking [ 8.30 am to 5.30 am]", "2023-05-30 20:14:51", 41),
        ))

        coEvery { parkingService.getETA(Pair(44.57317333333334, -123.282065), Pair(44.568078130296776, -123.279363220437)) } returns 60.0
        coEvery { parkingService.getETA(Pair(44.57317333333334, -123.282065), Pair(44.56298278509426, -123.27235573138302)) } returns 50.0

        viewModel.getNearestParkingLot(mockApiResponse, currentLocation)
        // Then
        coVerify {
            parkingService.getETA(Pair(44.57317333333334, -123.282065), Pair(44.568078130296776, -123.279363220437))
            parkingService.getETA(Pair(44.57317333333334, -123.282065), Pair(44.56298278509426, -123.27235573138302))
        }

        val expectedWeight = 12 / 60.0
        val expectedWeight1 = 3 / 50.0
        val expectedList: MutableList<Pair<parking_lots, Double>> = mutableListOf()
        expectedList.add(Pair(mockApiResponse.parking_lots[0], expectedWeight))
        expectedList.add(Pair(mockApiResponse.parking_lots[1], expectedWeight1))

        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(expectedList,
            viewModel.parkinglotsWeightsLiveData?.value
        )
        assertEquals(mockApiResponse.parking_lots[0], viewModel.nearestParkinglotsLiveData?.value)
        assertEquals(60.0, viewModel.durationInSecLiveData?.value)
        assertTrue(viewModel.parkinglotsWeightsLiveData?.value?.size == 2)
    }
}
```

GotlinitHub actions file:

```
name: Kotlin CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        
    - name: Change wrapper permissions
      run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      
    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1
      with:
        arguments: build
```

I want to add these test cases to run with github actions. All test cases pass locally but fails in CI/CD (github actions).
I also tried writing same test cases using Mockito, but that also didn't work.
I also have verified  env variables.
Test cases even run using gradlew command locally.

GitHub Actions Logs:

Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLots is called and succeeds, should return SUCCESS loading state
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: ParkingService(#32).getParkingLots(any())) was not called
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.failIfNotPassed(VerifyingState.kt:66)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.VerifyingState.recordingDone(VerifyingState.kt:42)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:47)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:64)
at io.mockk.impl.eval.VerifyBlockEvaluator.verify(VerifyBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalCoVerify(API.kt:143)
at io.mockk.MockKKt.coVerify(MockK.kt:175)
at io.mockk.MockKKt.coVerify$default(MockK.kt:172)
at com.example.msproject.HomeViewModelTest$Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLots is called and succeeds, should return SUCCESS loading state$1.invokeSuspend(HomeViewModelTest.kt:93)
at com.example.msproject.HomeViewModelTest$Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLots is called and succeeds, should return SUCCESS loading state$1.invoke(HomeViewModelTest.kt)
at com.example.msproject.HomeViewModelTest$Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLots is called and succeeds, should return SUCCESS loading state$1.invoke(HomeViewModelTest.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:208)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$2.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:55)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:112)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(TestBuilders.kt:207)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:167)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt$createTestResult$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuildersJvm.kt:13)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:279)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:12)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:166)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:154)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:147)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(Unknown Source)
at com.example.msproject.HomeViewModelTest.Given showProgressLoader is true when getParkingLots is called and succeeds, should return SUCCESS loading state(HomeViewModelTest.kt:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74

Comment: Could you add a link to the failed job or add some output data?

Comment: Hi, 
I have just added GitHub actions logs.